# mysql cluster - mysqld node failed to connect to mgmt node

Tags: mysql, database

I am trying to setup a mysql cluster but was unable to get the mysqld node to connect to the mgmt node.

This is the error I received when I issue the command with -show warnings

```
    C:\Program Files\MySQL\cluster\MySQL_Cluster\My_Cluster>mysqld –defaults-file=c
onf\my.102.cnf.txt -show
120310 2:49:27 [Warning] Can’t create test file C:\Program Files\MySQL\cluster\
ow\des.lower-test
120310 2:49:27 [Warning] Can’t create test file C:\Program Files\MySQL\cluster\
ow\des.lower-test
mysqld: Can’t change dir to ‘C:\Program Files\MySQL\cluster\ow\’ (Errcode: 2)
120310 2:49:28 [ERROR] Aborting
120310 2:49:28 [Note] mysqld: Shutdown complete
```

I have looked through the web and most answers point to a permission issue. I have setup a "everyone" user group and assigned full control(r/w) to the mysql folder but it still not working. The setup is based on a windows environment.

Does anyone have any ideas to this?

Comment: were you able to fix the issue? I am facing the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

hopefully the windows getting started guide can help:
http://downloads.mysql.com/tutorials/cluster/GetMySQLClusterRunning-Windows.pdf

Answer (score 0):

try to start your command prompt with Run as Administrator hope this works.

Answer (score 0):

Dont install mysql in Program Files, install it in C:/mysql/ and that should fix any permission problem